# Trying to add multiple records with a while loop to a MYSQL table defined by a field in case they dont already exist

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, sql-insert

I have a table named "Payments"
this table looks like this

```
HouseNumber| Month | Amount| Status
```

I have 104 houses to administrate, hows numbers go from 1 to 104, so far, only 5 houses have paid March rent and I made an insert to my table for those ones.

If you run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE Month = "March"
```

you get the following result

```
 - HouseNumber| Month | Amount| Status 
 - 1          |March  |   370 | Paid
 - 16         |March  |   370 | Paid
 - 24         |March  |   370 | Paid
 - 46         |March  |   370 | Paid
 - 99         |March  |   370 | Paid
```

What im trying is to do an insert for the other 99 houses with the status "Not Paid"

I can come up with a couple ways to achive this goal but I feel non of them is the best practice to do it.

I thought about doing it manualy 99 insert statments 
Or selecting the paid housenumber and adinging them to a PHP array and make the inserts with a PHP loop
I actualy came of with a query but im getting many syntax errors

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE myproc()
BEGIN
     DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE march (housenumber int);

    WHILE (i <= 104) DO

        IF i NOT IN (SELECT `housenumber` FROM Payments WHERE `Month` = "2020-03-01")
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO March (housenumber) VALUES (i)
                SET i = i + 1
            END

    END WHILE;

    SELECT * FROM marc;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

I want to be able to to this with only one query

Comment: Is there another table where the list of the 104 houses can be found?

Comment: Create a table of sequential numbers. Then you can select numbers in a range like `WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND 104`, and join that with the `Payments` table to get the missing numbers.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Barmar, a typical solution involves using a number table.

Here is a query that creates a table that contains all numbers from `0` to `999`:

```
create table nums as
select n1.n + 10 * n10.n + 100 * n100.n n
from (
    select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
    union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
) n1
cross join (
    select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
    union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
) n10
cross join (
    select 0 n union all select 1 union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4
    union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all select 8 union all select 9
) n100
```

You can then use that table to generate the "missing" rows in your original table:

```
insert into payments(house_number, month, amount, status)
select n.n, '2020-03-01', 370, 'Not Paid'
from nums n
where 
    n.n between 1 and 104
    and not exists (
        select 1 from payments p where p.month = '2020-03-01' and p.house_number = n.n
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially load your table with default values for all houses -

```
- HouseNumber| Month | Amount| Status 
- 1          |March  |   370 | Not Paid
- 2          |March  |   370 | Not Paid
- 3          |March  |   370 | Not Paid
- 4          |March  |   370 | Not Paid
- 5          |March  |   370 | Not Paid
```

to 104. Then when a house pays their rent simply update the `Status` field to `Paid`. Wouldn't that be easier?